# Initialization Pattern?

Tags: design-patterns

Say I have class A:

```
public class A
{
  private B _b;

  public class A(B b)
  {
    Assert.That(b != null);
    _b = b;
  }
}
```

And object b needs some complex initialization, like:

```
b.Prop1 = ...
b.Prop2 = ...
b.Prop3 = ...

int answerToSomeComplexFormula = PerformComplexFormula();

b.Prop4 = answerToSomeCopmlexFormula

etc...
```

I do not want to perform this initialization in the constructor.  Is there a name for some pattern that describes returning an object that has complex initialization?  Something like:

```
public class BInitializer
{
   public B Create()
   {
      B b = new B();
      // set up properties
      return b;
   }
}

BInitializer initializer = new BInitializer();
B b = initializer.Create();

A a = new A(b)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution with BInitializer is very good and it is called [Factory Method](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/creational_patterns) design pattern.

Here you can find some common creational design patterns: https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/creational_patterns

Comment: Interesting.  I was under the impression that the factory pattern's sole responsibility was to more or less immediately return a concrete implementation.  If I used the factory pattern for the original question, I guess I could have an 'AFactory' that, as part of it's Create() method, instantiates and initializes a B object, and then returns a new A(b)?  That would still be considered a factory, right?

Comment: You can do like that. Additionaly you can make the AFactory to take an BInitializer object as a parameter in the constructor, to make it even more loosely coupled. A always try to think if my implementation: is 1. easy to use 2. easy to understand 3. (unit) testable.

Comment: Why not forgo the AFactory altogether, and have A take a BInitializer as part of it's constructor (and call _b = bInitializer.Create() )?  Would A still be considered testable in that case?  Any disadvantages to that?

Comment: It is also a not bad idea. It depends on your tests. Because when you will be testing class `A` then in your tests you will have to inject an `BInitializer` via contructor. As the result your tests might be less readable. A workaround would be to have two constructors for `A`: 1. `public class A(BInitializer factory)` for client API 2. `internal class A(B b)` - only for testing.

Comment: Isn't it is more suitable for Builder rather than Factory?

Comment: Builder is useful when you decouple the whole building process. The StringBuilder is the simplest example. I think that here we just want to initialize/inject a dependency - that means make sure that the A instances are always ready to use.